# How to get SonarQube (running in docker container) to connect to localhost:9000 from Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, networking, sonarqube, localhost

I am running SonarQube on both java and javascript code inside a CentOS VM. I pulled the sonarqube docker image and am running the container. I exposed port 9000 and am able to open up localhost:9000 and interact with the sonarqube gui. When I run the sonar-scanner from the command line on the JavaScript code using this command:

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=javascript_code -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin
```

I get a fully analyzed project. As well as the JavaScript code I can run it on the Java code using the maven build. Both work correctly from the command line.

When I add it into a Jenkins Pipeline I do the exact same commands and get the following:

```
Error: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached

Caused by: Fail to get bootstrap index from server

Caused by: Failed to connect to localhost:9000

Caused by: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I also tried when starting the container to use --network="host" instead of publishing port 9000, but it still does not connect from the Jenkins Pipeline. Everything works correctly when I am running the commands from the Command Line, just when I try to put it into a Jenkins Pipeline.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

*Edit: Using the sonarqube plugin I was able to get my analysis to run as a Jenkins Job. However, when I try to add the analysis into the pipeline I get the same SonarQube server cannot be reached error. It says it skips my project because the project has been banned form the build due to previous failures and gives me this error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar (default-cli) on project sonarqubeproj: 
Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: unexpected end of stream on Connection{localhost:9000, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}: \n not found: limit=0 content=… -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar (default-cli) on project feedback-tool-ui: Unable to execute SonarQube
```

Comment: Is the pipeline using another user not known by SonarQube?

Comment: how do you run jenkins? i assume you are using a docker image for jenkins? might be that localhost called from this jenkins docker image is just referencing the docker image, and not the sonarqube image. i am not sure, how you spin up your docker images, but if you use docker-compose you could easily use the provided name instead of localhost

Comment: The pipeline is using a user known by SonarQube. I am using the docker image for jenkins, but I didn't use docker-compose when starting it up. Do you suggest I use the ip address and not localhost?

Comment: yes that could solve the issue too :D

Comment: @user10620554 did you resolve your issue? How did you resolve it? I have the same issue, where I'm running Jenkins from a container and a SonarQube instance from the host (although my SonarQube server is not containerized). Everything works fine from the command line but I get the "server can't connect error when I trigger my pipeline build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is most likely related to how you run jenkins.

I assume you also run jenkins via docker. this means that in the context of jenkins, localhost is not your host system, but the jenkins container. This means you need to adapt your sonarqube-url to reference the host system.

Therefore you have multiple options:

1. use the public ip of the host system
2. use the docker ip of the host system
3. resolve the ip via dns. docker has an internal DNS and if those container run in the same network, you can normally reach them by containername.

sidenote:
i am not sure if you are using docker-compose or kubernetes, but if you are not using it, you might also want to dive into docker-compose as it is just a simple yaml-config in which you can easily start up servers.

Comment: I agree that it has to be something how jenkins is run...I tried doing what you suggested. For the public ip of the host I got the same error as above and when I tried the docker ip of host system I got a connection refused error. It doesn't let me curl the docker ip from inside the jenkins container or the pipeline so I think it is an issue with how jenkins is interacting with the docker network. I am going to try to see if I can run jenkins in another way to get it to work

Comment: Thanks, I used the public IP of my PC and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used the  sonarqube container ip address in jenkins  it worked.